# Remove Underline for Hyperlink and strike some elements : text-decoration: none with text-decoration: line-through

Tags: css, text-decorations

So what I am trying to achieve here is that, I do not want any hyperlink to be underlined and at the same time I want some elements to be strike through.

Both of them work fine individually, but I can not get to work both of them together.

*Code:*

```
a:link    {
    text-decoration:  none 
  } 

.deceased {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Comment: Please add your HTML structure.

Comment: It is a JSF page. <h:commandLink styleClass="#{person.gender } #{person.alive}"... person.gender resolves to either F or M (both of them are css classes), which works fine. person.alive resolves to deceased if person is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would guess the issue is that of selector specifity. I believe the a:link selector is more specific so it takes precedence over the .deceased. I would say the easiest solution would be to change the specificity.

check here
http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/
and here
http://dorward.me.uk/www/underline/

Comment: No, .deceased is *less* specific, so a:link takes precedence. The reason a:link is more specific is because of the type selector (a). The class selector and pseudo-class are equal. But yes, increasing specificity is the solution here.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. There was nothing I could do to increase specifity, so I had to reduce the specificity of "a:link" down to "a". It worked, Thanks alot.

Comment: Glad to help, I learned something in the process, thanks BoltClock.